# Удаление элемента из бинарного дерева С++

Tags: c++, указатели, бинарное-дерево, ref

Написал код удаление элемента из дерева, не понятно как передвигать элемент после удаление
Код приведен ниже

Структура

````
#include <memory>

struct tree_node {
    int value;
    tree_node *up;
    std::unique_ptr<tree_node> left, right;
    tree_node(int val, tree_node *parent = nullptr) : value(val), up(parent) {}
};

struct tree {
    std::unique_ptr<tree_node> root;

    auto remove(int val) -> bool;
};

Сам код 
```auto tree::remove(int val) -> bool {
   
    auto uzel= std::ref(root);
    while (uzel.get() && uzel.get()->value != val)
        uzel= val < uzel.get()->value ? uzel.get()->left
                                             : uzel.get()->right;
    if (uzel.get() == nullptr)
        return false;
    else if (val < uzel.get()->value) {
        uzel.get->left = std::move(uzel.get()->left), val;
    } else if (val > uzel.get()->value) {
        uzel.get()->right = std::move(uzel.get()->right), val;
    } else if (uzel.get()->left && uzel.get()->right == nullptr) {
        uzel.get() = std::move(uzel.get()->up);
    } else {
        if (uzel.get()->left) {
            uzel.get()->left->up = uzel.get()->up;
            uzel.get() = std::move(uzel.get()->left);
        } else if (uzel.get()->right) {
            uzel.get()->right->up = uzel.get()->up;
            uzel.get() = std::move(uzel.get()->right);
        } else {
            uzel.get() = nullptr;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
````

Comment: Вот очень хорошая лекция по этой теме <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkLLcdgJj_o&t=3327s>(там минут 30-40, не все 2 часа). Скорее всего, ваш код далек от эффективности. Ответ на ваш вопрос там тоже будет.

Comment: очень плохая лекция

Comment: Если у узла только одна не нулевая ссылка, то меняете соответствующую ссылку на узел у его родителя на нее (если все нулевые, то обнуляете ссылку у родителя). Если есть обе ссылки, то ищете в правой ветке узел с нулевой левой ссылкой и заменяете ее на ссылку влево из удаляемого узла. В родителе заменяете ссылку на удаляемый узел его правой ссылкой.